# Need a Relay Alternative

Tags: power

I have an application that needs a XBee and another module to be turned on and off digitally via a microcontroller.

The Setup is 2 XBee's and an application board is connected to the Microcontroller. On PowerON I need 1 Xbee and the Microcontroller to come on and do its routines. After the uC gets the signal from the Xbee (wirelessly from a baseStation) the board has to turn on the other XBee and application board. And when the operation is over, the XBee and Board is to be powered back down. I dont want to put them in sleep or low power state, just power both those devices off.

I was thinking of using a relay. But i cannot find a 3.3v 1A SMD Equivalent system. I am looking for a SMD type of footprint to go on a very compact board.

What options do i have?

The XBee needs around 1A Power and the Application board 500mA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XBee sleep mode is supposed to be less than 10uA, so (if you can get it working) then use that.

A P-FET on the high side can be used to turn off anything, you'll need to drive it with a signal transistor to switch it from the mcu - e.g. [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=112521.msg845816#msg845816) or google for *FET high side switch*.

Comment: Ok so i can use a Transistor -> MOSFET -> To control the Power Pin of the device boards. Thats good. Thanks :) 

I'l find a equivalent MOSFET and Transistor. 

Just curious, is there a driver IC available like that to do the job?